# Custom Progress Indicator - Animate subviews color overlay left to right

Tags: xcode, swift, uikit

I have a container UIView that contains many columns/subviews.

I want to create a color fill animation on the container UIView, left to right as demonstrated on the image below, so it gradually changes the colors of only the subviews.

How to achieve this?
Im guessing i would have to create a mask and move it over this container UIView?
But then how to achieve that the mask only applies to the subviews?

EDIT:

this is a progress indicator for a playing audio file, so it needs to indicate the current time position precisely.
Also i must be able to have the shapes in different sizes as they represent audio waves

[image: what i want to achieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it the opposite to the way you describe it. I would draw your audio wave shapes as a mask, thus revealing whatever is behind them. It is then trivial to position / animate a colored rectangle rightwards behind the mask to indicate the progress through the music:

[image]

In other words, the color is not an overlay but an underlay.