# Fill in Horizontal View with Animation (Swift)

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to fill in a horizontal view (like a progress bar sort of) with an animation (so it will fill from the left edge to the right).

This is what I have but it isn't working

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let outlineView = UIView()
    outlineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    outlineView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    endorsementViews.append(outlineView)

    addSubview(outlineView)

    // custom UIView anchor extension
    outlineView.anchor(topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 12, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 75)

    let fillView = UIView()
    fillView.backgroundColor = .orange
    fillView.alpha = 0
    fillViews.append(fillView)

    outlineView.addSubview(fillView)

    // custom UIView anchor extension     
    fillView.anchor(outlineView.topAnchor, left: outlineView.leftAnchor, bottom: outlineView.bottomAnchor, right: nil, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 195, heightConstant: 0)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    for index in 0...2 {
        let fillWidth = 75

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.5) {
            self.fillViews[index].frame.size.width = fillWidth
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it "have" to use a `UIView` or can it use a `CALayer` or some other approach

Comment: Might want to see my approach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29553645/341994 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34971095/341994

Comment: I don't think you can set only the width. Try setting the whole frame. Also since you are using anchors. Use them to animate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change animation in `layoutSubviews()` method. If you change your view's size in animation your `fillView`'s size will change in animation too.

But if you want to change your `fillView`'s frame according to a stiuation: You should do it in an action(or function) and use `layoutIfNeeded()` method of your view in bottom of animation function like this:

```
func someFunction() {
    let fillWidth = 75
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.5)
       for index in 0...2 {
           self.fillViews[index].frame.size.width = fillWidth
       }
       self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

**Note:**
You should avoid to use `frame` property and constraints together to set frame to same view. You can change your view's constraints' properties in animation or set your view's frame in `layoutSubviews()` method and use a boolean control to check actual state of your subview to set a specific frame (if you need).